# Makefile_woes on multi directory

Tags: c, makefile

I'm resurrecting a project (Z80 sim with GTK GUI - GPL) and I'm rearranging the source.  The trouble is that my make skills are weak and I'm having trouble even with the online docs.  Can anyone give me some pointers?

The directory looks like this:

```
obj    src    z80
 |      |      |
 ------------------- z80sim.glade z80sim Makefile main.c
```

Where src is for the GUI src, z80 is for the simulator src and obj holds all the object files.  What I want to happen with the Makefile is for it to compile all the C and .h files in both src and z80 putting all .o files in obj.  Then to compile main.c, link it with all the .o files and put the executable in z80sim.

I have made a stab at the Makefile, so just so you can have a good laugh:

```
z80_srcs = disas.c  iosim.c  sim0.c  sim1.c  sim2.c  sim3.c  sim4.c  sim5.c  sim6.c  sim7.c  simctl.c  simfun.c  simglb.c  simglb.h  sim.h  simint.c
z80_objs = disas.o  iosim.o  sim0.o  sim1.o  sim2.o  sim3.o  sim4.o  sim5.o  sim6.o  sim7.o  simctl.o  simfun.o  simglb.o  simint.o
z80_dir = ./z80

VPATH = $(z80_dir)

EXE = z80sim

all:    $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(z80_objs)
        gcc -o z80em main.c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic

clean:
        rm -f $(EXE) *.o $(z80_dir)/*.o

$(z80_objs): $(z80_srcs)

        gcc -c -Wall $^
```

Which doesn't cut it at all!

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `"Which doesn't cut it at all!"`.  How (and from which directory) do you invoke `make`?  What output do you see and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I invoke make without flags or parameters from the same directory as the Makefile.  That partial make puts all the .o files in the main directory.

Comment: Why do you want exactly that directory structure? In particular why do you put all object files to the same single directory? Also, I'd suggest avoid using VPATH feature. If you are interested in simple and clean `makefiles`, I suggest you to use my template library for `GNU make`: https://github.com/igagis/prorab look for WIKI->tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen worse. Let's take it a little at a time.

```
z80_srcs = disas.c iosim.c sim0.c sim1.c sim2.c sim3.c sim4.c sim5.c sim6.c sim7.c simctl.c simfun.c simglb.c simglb.h sim.h simint.c
```

It usually isn't a good idea to glom source and header files together. Let's keep them separate:

```
z80_srcs = disas.c iosim.c sim0.c sim1.c sim2.c sim3.c sim4.c sim5.c sim6.c sim7.c simctl.c simfun.c simglb.c simint.c
z80_hdrs = simglb.h sim.h
```

I approve of listing them explicitly like that, but just so you know, you can have Make fine them with [the `wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function):

```
z80_srcs = $(wildcard src/*.c z80/*.c)
```

(But they will come with paths still attached, so you'll have to manage that.)
Also, as a passing note, the name `z80_srcs` is ambiguous, since it could refer to the sources in `z80`. Likewise, the name `src/` is misleading, since it does not contain all of the sources. But I think I know what you mean.

```
z80_objs = disas.o  iosim.o  ...
```

No need for that. Use [the `patsubst` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
z80_objs = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(z80_srcs))
```

But `disas.o iosim.o ...` is not as useful as `obj/disas.o obj/iosim.o ...`, so let's adjust the line:

```
z80_objs = $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(z80_srcs))
```

Now to build the objects.

```
$(z80_objs): $(z80_srcs)
    gcc -c -Wall $^
```

That works, but not the way you think. That's *one* rule that builds *all* the objects, whether they're out of date or not, in one operation. Effective, but crude. And it doesn't put the objects where you want them.

Let's build one object file, from the command line:

```
gcc -c -Wall disas.c
```

That won't work, for a couple of reasons. 1) The compiler can't find `disas.c`, 2) it also can't find `sim.h`, which `disas.c` requires, and 3) it will try to build the object file in the working directory. Here's a solution, and it behooves you to study and understand it, not just copy and paste:

```
gcc -c -Wall src/disas.c -Isrc -o obj/disas.o
```

So we can write a rule:

```
obj/disas.o: src/disas.c
    gcc -c -Wall src/disas.c -Isrc -o obj/disas.o
```

This answer is getting long, so I'll jump right to the pattern rule. Once again I urge you to *study and understand,* rather than parrot.

```
vpath %.c src z80

obj/%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -Wall $< -Isrc -o $@
```

And the executable:

```
obj/$(EXE): $(z80_objs)
    gcc -o $@ main.c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic $^
```

Comment: Minor 'nitpick': `vpath *.c src z80` should be `vpath %.c src z80` .

Comment: `$(z80_objs): $(z80_srcs)` isn't one rule that builds all the objects.  It's one rule _per object_ that builds all the objects with one compile line.  If you ever tried to use `-j` for parallel builds this would fail spectacularly.

Comment: @G.M.: Not a minor nitpick, an important correction; thank you. (I could have sworn I copied that line from the testing makefile...)

Comment: @MadScientist: It's one rule, which will be called many times unnecessarily, but I hadn't thought of the danger of using it in parallel. Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the extremely helpful advice from Beta (and G.M.), I think I have it cracked.  Here is the new Makefile:

```
z80_srcs = disas.c iosim.c sim0.c sim1.c sim2.c sim3.c sim4.c sim5.c sim6.c sim7.c simctl.c simfun.c simglb.c simint.c
z80_hdrs = simglb.h sim.h 
gui_srcs = callbacks.c code.c guiglb.c  interface.c iosim.c memory.c support.c flags.c interface.h log.c ports.c registers.c
gui_hdrs = prototypes.h callbacks.h guiglb.h interface.h support.h

z80_objs = $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(z80_srcs))
gui_objs = $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(gui_srcs))

EXE = z80sim

vpath %.c gui z80

obj/%.o: %.c
        gcc -c -Wall $< `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -Igui -Iz80 -o $@

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(z80_objs) $(gui_objs)
        gcc -o $@ main.c -Wall -Iz80 -Igui `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic $^

clean:
        rm -f $(EXE) *.o obj/*.o
```

My only concern is that the header files don't appear to be scanned by make.  Should I add a %.h after the %.c?

Then all I have to do is tidy up the code and port it from GTK2 to GTK3 (sob!)

Comment: Dealing with the header files is a problem I didn't address because my answer was getting too long. The crude, inefficient, easy way is to make *every* object depend on *all* header files: `obj/%.o: %.c $(z80_hdrs)`. The better, painstaking way is to add the dependencies by hand, since you know what they are, since you wrote the code: `obj/disas.o: sim.h`. The advanced method of automatic dependency handling is laid out in detail in [Mad Scientist's paper](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation).